# Navigation case don't work when using h:form enctype="multipart/form-data" with f:ajax

Tags: ajax, jsf, navigation, multipartform-data

I'm trying to create a navigation case that can be called by a backing bean action or a outcome link, so I created this in faces-config.xml:

```
<navigation-case>
    <from-outcome>curso-list</from-outcome>
    <to-view-id>/core/curso/curso-list.xhtml</to-view-id>
    <redirect />
</navigation-case>
```

This works for outcome link but didn't work for actions. So I added this:

```
<navigation-case>
    <from-action>#{cursoDetalheMB.salvar}</from-action>
    <from-outcome>curso-list</from-outcome>
    <to-view-id>/core/curso/curso-list.xhtml</to-view-id>
    <redirect />
</navigation-case>
```

But now the outcome didn't work too. I noted that problem occurs when I use ajax inside my form. If I don't make any ajax request the action redirect works normally, but when I make some ajax request the action redirect don't work.

**I found the problem** but i don't know how to fix. My form before the ajax request:

```
<form id="j_idt60" name="j_idt60" method="post" action="/project/core/teste.xhtml" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

My form after the ajax request:

```
<form id="j_idt60" name="j_idt60" method="POST" action="http://localhost:8080/project/core/teste.xhtml" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="JSFFrameId">
<input type="hidden" name="j_idt60" value="j_idt60">
```

Note the "target" property, if i remove this the navigation works fine but i don't know why jsf add this property.

Comment: no, i'm using h:commandLink and my backingBean have a "action".

Comment: 4 letters: mcve, [mcve].Also read http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Comment: So you're using Mojarra 2.2. Which version exactly? Tried latest? (2.2.12 as of now)

Comment: @BalusC, i was using "2.2.6", so i change to "2.2.12" and problem was solved partially. When i use ajax inside h:inputFile that problem occur again.

Comment: A solution that i found is use "render=@form" inside ajax h:inputFile. I don't know if exists a better solution for this.

Comment: render=@form solved the problem but it creates really bad user experience

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSF no redirect request after file input ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36623750/jsf-no-redirect-request-after-file-input-ajax)