# JSF no redirect request after file input ajax

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a form in JSF 2.2:

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h:outputLabel>title *</h:outputLabel>
    <h:inputText value="#{bean.title}" required="" />

    <h:outputLabel>Image *</h:outputLabel>
    <h:inputFile value="#{bean.picutreFile}" a:accept="image/*">
        <f:ajax listener="#{bean.uploadPicture}" />
    </h:inputFile>

    <h:commandLink action="#{bean.save}">
        Save
    </h:commandLink>
</h:form>
```

The functions:

```
public String save() {
    return "/index?faces-redirect=true";
}

public void uploadPicture() {
    // Do nothing
}
```

But after I choose an image and get the call of `uploadPicture` function, the `save` function can't redirect the page. It calls to `save` but the redirect is not working, and just refresh the current page.

If I skip the file upload, it redirects normally. How can I make it to work?

**EDIT**
I have noticed that if I remove the ajax `<f:ajax listener="#{bean.uploadPicture}" />` it works as expected. But I must to have that ajax because I want to display the image after upload.

**EDIT 2**
I can see that after the ajax called, the JSF creates a weird iframe at the bottom of the page with `partial-response` tag in it's body, and when I press 'Save` **that** iframe is redirects to the destination. Why is that??

Comment: Which JSF impl/version? Early 2.2 versions have childhood bugs with h:inputFile. See also http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info for hints.

Comment: @BalusC When I open the JSF's JAR inside the GlassFish libraries in NetBeans I can see `Bundle-Name: Mojarra JSF Implementation 2.2.12 (20150720-0848) https:/
 /svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.12@14885`, I am also using GlassFish 4.1.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reproduced it. I do agree that the behavior is confusing and unintuitive, but I wouldn't say this is a bug in the JSF implementation, because you're essentially mixing ajax with regular requests which is wrong in first place. See also this related question [httpError: The Http Transport returned a 0 status code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23641691/httperror-the-http-transport-returned-a-0-status-code).

The correct approach is **either** to make the command link an ajax link as well,

```
<h:commandLink action="#{bean.save}">
    Save
    <f:ajax execute="@form" />
</h:commandLink>
```

**or** to remove `<f:ajax>` from the `<h:inputFile>` (and perform upload processing in `save()`).

```
<h:inputFile value="#{bean.picutreFile}" a:accept="image/*" />
```

That iframe you're seeing is by the way the age-old trick to simulate asynchronous behavior during file uploads, invented long before [XHR2 / FormData API](http://caniuse.com/#feat=xhr2) was standardized. This approach was during JSF 2.2 development preferred over XHR2 due to better backwards compatibility in webbrowsers (particularly MSIE). See also a.o. [How to make Asynchronous(AJAX) File Upload using iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909442/how-to-make-asynchronousajax-file-upload-using-iframe)

Comment: I didn't know that mixing ajax with regular is wrong, because the ajax was just for display preview of the image. But with `<f:ajax execute="@form" />` its works perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

As I know  JSF blocks your request till ajax call for security. Maybe you can put a processing bar or something like that while ajax calling. So user can not click save button until ajax call finish.

Can you wait a little bit after clicking upload button then click save button? It should work If i am right.

Comment: When I debug it, I press "Save" after `uploadPicture` ends. Isn't good enough? BTW, I am using 5KB photos only so I don't think it's need so much waiting time